# Saving a log file if an error occurs

Tags: error-tracking, interruption

I am running a program that adds a message to a list after each completed cycle (about 5k cycles). Upon completion, the program saves the list to disk so I can review it.

However, if the program aborts, I lose the list. Can I write an error handler that, with its dying breath, will save that list?

Comment: Have a look at `CheckAbort` and `Catch`.

Comment: Still, if the kernel crashes, that might be of few use. A safer way would be to write the messages to file every now and then. See, e.g. `OpenAppend` and friends.

Comment: Have you looked at [`AbortProtect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbortProtect.html)?

Comment: I just discovered it.  It seems that wrapping everything in 'AbortProtect' and including 'TimeConstrained' would handle a lot.  I actually don't see many aborts, the program encounters an error of some in a function that never finishes evaluating.

Answer (score 10):

I think `` Internal`WithLocalSettings `` is the tool you want to use. The syntax is:

```
Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    preliminaryCode, (* can't be aborted *)
    body, (* can be aborted *)
    postprocessCode (* can't be aborted *)
]
```

Suppose your code looks like:

```
code[] := (a=1; b=2; Pause[Infinity]; c=3)
```

and you're interested in the values of `a`, `b` and `c`. Then:

```
Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    Null,
    code[],
    Print[{a, b, c}]
]
```

> {1,2,c}
>
> $Aborted[]

where I used `Evaluation | Abort Evaluation` (actually, the shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>). Note that `code[]` got aborted, yet the [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print) statement still occurred, where I use [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print) as a substitute for some sort of save file utility.